# What is personification?

Tags: structure

My friends talk about a few phrases in a book we read recently, as personification. I don't understand what it is. What is personification?

Comment: You may want to post this on the Literature.StackExchange site -- they're more for analyzing already written books, and this is more for creating them.

Comment: @Chenmunka, Since personification is something that a writer may well do in creating new work, this seems perfectly on topic here, and I don't see how this is 'too broad". I ask that it be reopened.

Comment: I don't want to come off rude, but there's a page on how to ask questions on this site, and if I remember correctly it asks you politely to try to find an answer on your own before bringing the question to SE. Usually it's not that big of a deal because its easier to come here than go searching everywhere for an answer. But this one you could literally type the exact question into google, bing, blackle, yahoo, duckduck go, yandex, and even swisscows, and get instant results that answer it perfectly. 

P.S.- I personally tested all of these search engines. safari works too if your using ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personification is when non-living things, or abstract ideas, are written of as if they were living beings, or particularly, given human qualities. "The sea crashed angrily against the shore." is a personification. The sea is not alive, and has no emotions. The reader is beign invited to view the sea, or perhaps the surf, as if it were a person, or at least a living being, and attribute emotion to it. This is a special case of a *metaphor* and in this cane is also an instance of the *pathetic fallacy* (assigning feeling to unfeeling nature).

A personification can be an extended passage, or even an entire work, although rarely. One could arge that the Greek, Roman, and Norse myths are extended personifications of natural forces into gods and other supernatural characters.

The term "Personification" can also be used to describe a situation in which human characteristics are attributed to a non-human, but living, being. *The Incredible Journey* , in which for much of the book the VP characters are two dogs and a cat, is essentially one long personification. So is Jack London's *White Fang* and Paul Gallico's *The Three Lives of Thomasina*. Ursula LeGuin's story, "The Direction of the Road" is narrated by an oak tree.

If the suggestion is being made that the object really is alive  and has the characteristics described, it is not a personification. A work of science fiction in which a sapient but very non-human character appears is not a personification. Neither would a work be in which it was seriously suggested that the earth was really a living and feeling being, as is done in sections of F. Paul Wilson's "Adversary cycle"

Comment: @bruglesco Is correct, personification can be applied to anything that isn't already a person. Pets and other animals are commonly personified in literature.

Comment: I would call that anthropification, but it could be considerd a form of personification, yes.

Comment: @bruglesco I edited my answer to add personification of non-human living beings, with some examples.

Comment: @linksassin  see edited answer.